# Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Tags: python, numpy

This is a part of my code

```
import numpy as np 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

import statistics as st



N = 2000 #tamaño de la señal

a = 1 #valor de la cte del proceso


time1 = np.arange(0.0, 0.2, 0.0005)

time2 = np.arange(0.2, 0.4, 0.0005)

time3 = np.arange(0.4, 0.6, 0.0005)

time4 = np.arange(0.6, 0.8, 0.0005)

print(len(time4))
```

And it prints 401

if i change it to

```
time4 = np.arange(0.4+2, 0.6+0.2, 0.0005)
```

it prints 400 as expected

Not sure why in the first code it prints 401

Comment: On `time4 = np.arange(0.4+2, 0.6+0.2, 0.0005)` you are actually adding 2 instead of 0.2 on the first parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `np.arange(0.6, 0.8, 0.0005)[-1] == 0.799999999999978`

Comment: So I suggest using `np.linspace` to get a fixed length array (eg `np.linspace(start, end, num=400)`)

Comment: Most of your code isn't needed to demonstrate the problem and should be removed. Then you could add your second example to demonstrate the difference. In fact `np.arange(0.4+2, 0.6+0.2, 0.0005)` is an empty array which would be seen on an working example.

Comment: You missed the warning in the docs.  With float steps, getting the end point right is tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Notice `numpy.arange()` is using `ceil` to count the numbers, for example,

```
a = np.arange(.1,.3,.1)
print(len(a)) # 2 
print(a)      # [0.1 0.2]

a = np.arange(.1,.4,.1)
print(len(a)) # 4
print(a)      # [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]
```

The result is not as simple as `(stop - start)/step`, due to ceilling, which adds up 1.

We can use numpy.linespace() if we know how many numbers we want, as below

```
a = np.linspace(.1,.4,3,endpoint=False) # do not include 0.4
print(len(a)) # 4
print(a)
```

Now let us try *time4*,

```
time4 = np.linspace(0.6, 0.8, 400,endpoint = False)
print(len(time4))
print(time4)
```

We can use parameter retstep to see the real step, as below,

```
time4 = np.linspace(0.6, 0.8, 400,endpoint = False, retstep=False)
print(time4[1]) # 0.0005000000000000001
```

Now we get real understanding of `ceilling`, and we rewrite the assignment,

```
time4 = np.arange(0.6, 0.8, 0.0005000000000000001)
print(len(time4)) # 401 again, no wonder

time4 = np.arange(0.6, 0.8 - 0.0005000000000000001, 0.0005000000000000001)
print(len(time4)) # 400 now, as expected
print(time4)
```

What `time4 = np.arange(0.4+0.2, 0.6+0.2, 0.0005)` does is the same, it puts the ceilling to 400, thus woks fine. Anyway, python **is not** pure math, it is just representing math :(